# What's the difference between mvn:deploy and mvn:install commands?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

I think there should be some difference, but can anyone tell me the details?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207281/what-is-the-difference-between-mvn-deploy-to-a-local-repo-and-mvn-install) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`mvn:install` copies your packaged Maven module to your local repository (by default, in `~/.m2/repository`), to be accessed by other local Maven builds.

`mvn:deploy` uploads your packaged Maven module to another (usually remote) repository, to be accessed by other, not necessarily local, Maven builds.

See the [documentation for the build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The `install` phase is responsible for the installation of artifacts into local **caching** repositories. This basically applies to the Maven repository, but a well-known example is also the OSGi Bundle Repository supported by *maven-bundle-plugin*.

The `deploy` phase is responsible for the installation of artifacts into **published** repositories. This usually applies to remote repositories, but is could perfectly be a local repository exposed to the outside world.

As all Maven phases, you can do with them anything you want. You can shuffle plugin phases as you see fit, but the above semantics is the conventional one and you should stick to it in order to be consistent with the default phases of other plugins' goals.

Answer (score 2):

`mvn:deploy` performs deployment to remote reposiory/environment, `mvn:install` installs all compiled packages to a local repository making them available to other builds performed on the local machine.

Comment: What do you mean by "all compiled packages"?

Comment: @Daniel, pom, jar, war, javadoc jar, source jar anything compiled/assembled by previous build phases.

Answer (score 1):

In one sentence: `mvn:install` compiles and installs your component in your local Maven repository, so that you can use it when other components used and developed locally depend on it. `mvn:deploy` deploys your (previously installed) component to a remote repository.

Comment: Does the module _really_ need to be installed before deploying?

Comment: I think the default life cycle of Maven contains that. And if you do only deploy it, what should be deployed then? See the documentation at http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html. there is stated: That is because if you call a build phase, it will execute not only that build phase, but also every build phase prior to the called build phase.

Comment: That's 2 sentences!