# How to get Sonatype Nexus to download the latest version of jar?

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

I'm using Sonatype Nexus 1.5.0 and a particular jar has a newer version in the Public Maven Central while my Nexus doesn't have it.

Assume that only the server where the Nexus is installed has the internet connection and my local laptop is not allowed to connect to internet directly, how to let the Nexus the download the newer version of the jar so that my local build can download the newer version from Nexus?

The settings.xml of my local Maven is configured with the URL of the Nexus to download the jars.

Please advise.

Comment: Do you get any error messages during your build? Have you configured that Nexus will download requested artifacts? Apart from that you should update your nexus cause the current version is 2.2?

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise, yes, you're right, there was an error in the server log that I didn't notice. It is due to the authentication expired so Nexus cannot connect to proxy to surf online to download jars. Now it works!

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9440427/944849) is a summary of how your local repository, remote repo (Nexus), and Maven Central work together.  If you have requested the new version of the jar in your POM, then it should end up in Nexus and your local artifact repo.  If it doesn't, something is not configured correctly, and @khmarbaise gave you some good starting points for troubleshooting in his comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Problem is solved by renewing the password to connect to the proxy.