# Deploy all 3rd party artifiacts from local repository

Tags: maven, deployment, artifacts

Is it possible to deploy all 3rd party artifiacts (some external libraries I am using in my project) from ~/.m2/repository to a specified remote repository?

I know that I can do it with one file e.g.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=ZZZ -DartifactId=XXX -Dversion=YYY -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by **3rd party artifacts** ?

Comment: you can find some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840984/maven-deploy-dependencies-to-remote-repository

Comment: It is exactly my question, but it wasn't resolved...